# PHP upload permission problem

Tags: php, linux, file-upload, permissions, chmod

right guys ive ran into a problem with file permissions with the following upload form. a text file is passed to the upload/ dir by global users.

```
mysite$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 user user 4096 2010-09-24 13:07 upload
```

but as I am not logged in as root, the new file uploaded to the domain saved itself in the upload/ dir with limiting permissions and cannot be modified. eg.

```
upload$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 3067 2010-09-24 13:07 Readme.txt
```

this problem is obviously the same for all files added to the upload folder by global users. once the file is uploaded I need a way of changing the file rights without embedding the root password into a php script running on the domain. please help!

is there any way to associate the same rights to files as the containing folder when new files are added?

submit form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

upload_file.php:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("/home/user/mysite/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "/home/user/mysite/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user, that initially writes the files into your "/upload" directory, is the one that started the Apache instance running a PHP module.

In other words, PHP is the "owner" of all uploaded files and through a PHP script you can change the permissions of all relevant uploaded files without providing any credentials at all:

[PHP chmod function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

A quick and dirty hack to make uploaded files writable to all users would be

```
else 
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 
      $f="/home/user/mysite/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); 
      chmod($f, 0777);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
      }
```

Comment: thanks for the hack, but after trying it instead of getting full rights I get some very strange permissions? '-r----x--t 1 www-data www-data    0 2010-09-24 15:53 readme.txt'

Comment: This because the file has sticky bit, which again comes with move_uploaded_files function.

Comment: looks like there was a typo. in PHP the correct format is 'chmod($f,0777)'. leading zero was missing. this now works perfectly!!

Comment: As well, you can make the `upload/` directory SETGID (mode 2xxx), which forces any new files within it to be created with the upload directory's group ownership.

Answer (score 3):

move_uploaded_file uses umask(600). Use `copy($source, $dest)` instead of move.

Comment: thanks for the umask(600) info on move_uploaded_file, where can I quickly reference more info like this? on the PHP module rights in linux

Comment: I checked it on my system by calling umask function before and after move_uploaded and copy function in a test php script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chmod`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) to change the file permissions.

To get the permissions of a file, use [`fileperms`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php).

Comment: thanks, but how can I use this permission output to solve the problem?

Comment: After you've uploaded the file, you can use `fileperms` on the folder to get the permissions, then use `chmod` with the result of `fileperms` to set the permissions as you want.

Comment: thanks for the tip, I could see how this could work for dynamic systems with multiple folders and users.