# PHP File upload not working in linux server

Tags: php, linux, file, file-upload, centos

The file upload works with xampp in windows but not working when I moved it to a production centos server. It throws "invalid file" error. This is the code I am using:

```
<?php
  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $extension = end($temp);
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
  || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
  && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
  && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
  }
  else
  {
   echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
   echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
   echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
   echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
  }
else
 {
 echo "Invalid file";
 }
 ?>
```

Can someone please help me with this........

Comment: check if upload folder is having write permission on production server.

Comment: and also check whether enctype="multipart/form-data" this set to Your form tag or not.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty the folder has a 777 permission

Comment: @ripa Ya its there........ checked it

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Error throws up during file upload. throws an "Invalid file" error

Comment: replace move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]); with  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);  --- try this and let me know

Comment: @winnyboy5 Any chance your file being uploaded has size more than the upload limit specified on your server?

Comment: Hmm check the file size it could an issue

Comment: @ripa thanks it worked. post it in the answer

Comment: @winnyboy5 I'm posting the above as answer. please accept and upvote the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace below line

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

with the below line

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

It'll solve Your problem.

Comment: @winnyboy5 this is the problem You are facing is permission issue. check http://www.projectpier.org/node/285

Comment: and also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787680/php-upload-permission-problem

Answer (score 0):

Locate the `php.ini` file and make sure that `file_upload` is enabled and not commented.

```
    sudo find / -name php.ini
```

edit:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.x or 7.4 your version/apache2/php.ini
```

uncomment:

```
file_upload=no
file_max_filesize=100M
max_file_uploads= 200
```

Make sure your php file upload script contains the correct upload folder directory (`./upload/` or `/upload` or `upload/`).

Check if the upload folder has the required permission:
"normally all files on a server must have the following permission: 644 and all folders 755"

```
sudo chmod 755 -R your-upload-folder
```

if notm try with `chmod 777`

```
    sudo chown username:usergroup your-upload-folder
```

restart your server.
Apache:

```
    sudo service apache2 restart
```

Nginx:

```
    sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxsBJBa9bQM