# Error permission denied while chmod on linux server

Tags: php, linux, server

I host a website on linux server, I have got an error chmod permission denied error. Basically i want to change file permission chmod(0755) after file upload for security purpose..Any one has any idea..
[PHP upload permission problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787680/php-upload-permission-problem)

Comment: So I guess you are lacking the required permissions to issue that command. Just a wild guess though.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running PHP under apache. You will need to make sure apache has permission to perform this action. If you are calling php via the command line, make sure the user that calls the script has permission to perform this action